# Get data from WHERE Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I have this tables: `users` `contacts` and `user_providers`, this is the structure of each one:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to get all the contacts from a specific user id in contacts table and user_provider provider_name in user_providers , i have this query

```
SELECT c.id, c.contact_name,c.description,c.discharge,c.latitude,c.longitude,c.town,c.country,c.province,
  (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT cn.number) FROM contact_numbers cn WHERE cn.contact_id = c.id) AS numbers,
  (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT ce.email)  FROM contact_emails  ce WHERE ce.contact_id = c.id) AS emails
  FROM
   contacts c,
   user_providers po
  WHERE
   c.user_id = 1 and po.provider_name = 'google'
  ORDER BY
   c.id;
```

But when im trying to get the data it comes like this:
[image]

The query doesnt respect the provider_name, it returns all contacts related only with a specific user id.

Image from stored data:
**contactsTable**
[image]
**user_provider Table**
[image]

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Your question is not clear.  The first result set is presumably created because all those rows match your filter conditions.

Comment: I will re-edit this post!

Comment: can you show the `provider_name` data for the 3 rows that you have in the picture?

Comment: Sure, hold on! +

Comment: No, i think i cant show the `provider_name` in the 3 rows, my idea is to get the data using two conditionals, in this case `user_id` in `contact` table and `provider_name` in `user_providers`

Comment: How do you know that the query is not correct? Maybe the 3 rows have the `provider_name` as `google`?

Comment: Nope, the three rows doesnt have `provider_name`, they are from a specific user, and i want to get all the `contacts` from a specific user and provider_name,i will add some photos about the info in the database

Comment: It seems like you are getting the correct results. There are three contacts for user with ID = 1, and however you join the provider table, you will always have at least 3 rows. The provider name doesn't matter because if it's `google` or `facebook` the user ID is still the same and the user's contacts are still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you are getting the correct results for your query because the tables `contacts` and `user_providers` do not have a relationship other than the `user_id` column.

And since the `user_id` is the same for all three rows in the `contacts` table you will always get at least 3 rows. The number of rows you will get will be: `number of contacts for specific user id * number of user providers for a specific user id`

For example, doing a select without `provider_name` in the where clause, gets you: 3 (contacts) * 2 (providers)

```
id  contact_name  provider_name
-------------------------------
1   Vacio         google
2   Vacio2        google
3   Vaciogiogle   google
1   Vacio         facebook
2   Vacio2        facebook
3   Vaciogiogle   facebook
```

What you can do is create another relationship between `contacts` and `user_providers` tables. For example, add a `provider_id` column to the `contacts` table where you will store the ID of the provider from the `user_providers` table. Then you can use the below SQL join the tables and actually filter on the `provider_name`.

```
SELECT c.id, c.contact_name, up.provider_name 
FROM contacts c 
LEFT JOIN user_providers up ON c.provider_id = up.provider_id 
WHERE c.user_id = 1 AND up.provider_name = 'google';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `JOIN` between the tables.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  I think this is you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT up.user_id, c.contact_name
FROM contacts c JOIN
     user_providers up
     ON c.id = up.user_id
WHERE up.user_id = 1 AND up.provider_name = 'facebook'       
ORDER BY up.user_id;
```

However, the `JOIN` conditions are not obvious from your query.